# PowerPivot for Sharepoint 2013 - Cannot generate thumbnail error

Tags: error, powerpivot

I'm trying to get the thumbnail to appear in the PowerPivot Gallery. However I'm getting the error message

> "An error occurred while capturing snapshots for this document".

I've tried disabling Loopback checking by following this [guide](http://blogs.technet.com/b/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/archive/2012/12/06/invoking-and-analyzing-the-getsnapshot-exe.aspx)

But still to no avail. Please help.

Comment: BTW this is the error I'm getting:

<Error>Terminating capture process: 'Illegal redirection to resources outside of the web application: 'res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm''</Error>

Comment: How large is the workbook? Take a look at this [site](http://blogs.technet.com/b/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/archive/2012/12/06/invoking-and-analyzing-the-getsnapshot-exe.aspx). Also, does the workbook render when you open it in full screen.

Comment: Hi, the workbook is 2.22 MB in size and yes it renders when I open it in full screen. Thanks for the link but I've already tried the methods described in that site. The error i'm getting is "<Error>Terminating capture process: 'Illegal redirection to resources outside of the web application: 'res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm''</Error>" which was supposed to be resolved by method #3. However it didn't work.